# BuildAsmmeta task failed unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio-2005, compact-framework

Anyone else run into this issue, or have any ideas on how I can start to investigate this error?

> The "BuildAsmmeta" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided.
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
>      at Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.Tasks.BuildAsmmeta.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteTask(ExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Hashtable projectItemsAvailableToTask, BuildPropertyGroup projectPropertiesAvailableToTask, Boolean& taskClassWasFound)

This occurs when trying to build a Pocket PC (Compact Framework 2) application, using VS2005

This project builds without issue on my old Windows 8 box, but since updating to Windows 10 I haven't ever managed to get things working. It's possible (likely) I've missed installing something along the way

Any wisdom gratefully appreciated. I'd like to move away from Windows 8 at some point!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the BuildAsmmeta task, which is used to keep design time attributes of user controls in separate dlls.
I didn't need them so I focused on simply disabling the task...
One solution is to simply remove any xmta files from your project, if it is not a user control library.
Another option is to disable the task, by editing `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.CompactFramework.Common.targets` file.

Add some Condition  to the BuildAsmmeta tags by editing it like this:

```
<Target Name="BuildAsmmeta" Condition="'$(BuildAsmmeta)' == 'true'">
<Target Name="CopyAsmmetaFilesToOutputDirectory" Condition="'$(BuildAsmmeta)' == 'true'">
```

Don't forget to restart VS2005.
This way you can turn it on later by adding an environment variable BuildAsmmeta to the OS.